# How can I open a connection to "Coinex" websocket using "WebSocketSharp" in C#

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I'm currently working om my very own trade bot and I want to stream realtime cryptocurrency price from coinex.com using **websocket** (documentation is here: "https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki").
I start with a windows form project in Visual Studio and add **websocketsharp** *Nuget package* to make a connection using this two lines of code:

```
            WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("wss://socket.coinex.com/");
            ws.Connect();
```

but connection is not stablished and I can't continue working on other parts of my program.
after a week searching and googling I have no success. I appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: I need open a websocket connection between my client program and Coinex server.

Comment: This Error Rise up:  "System.invalidOperationException: The current state of the connection is not open."

Comment: Which line does the exception originate from?  ws.Connect or another line?

Comment: the error rise on other line because the "ws.connect" do not establish a successful connection.

Comment: I find the problem. the "Coinex.com" do not accessible without VPN. I have to use PROXY to connect the Coinex server. But I don't know how to set proxy for my program. I use Psiphon as a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem. The Coinex.com domain restricted (Blocked) here (In IRAN) and I should use Proxy to bypass restriction. But here there is another problem: How can I set Proxy for websocketsharp? there is a "Setproxy" function in "websocketsharp" but do not work.